# binary search array overflow c++

Tags: c++, arrays, binary

I'm a Computer Science student. This is some code that I completed for my Data Structures and Algorithms class. It compiles fine, and runs correctly, but there is an error in it that I corrected with a band-aid. I'm hoping to get an answer as to how to fix it the right way, so that in the future, I know how to do this right.

The object of the assignment was to create a binary search. I took a program that I had created that used a heap sort and added a binary search. I used Visual Studio for my compiler.

My problem is that I chose to read in my values from a text file into an array. Each integer in the text file is separated by a tabbed space. In line 98, the file reads in correctly, but when I get to the last item in the file, the counter (n) counts one time too many, and assigns a large negative number (because of the array overflow) to that index in the array, which then causes my heap sort to start with a very large negative number that I don't need. I put a band-aid on this by assigning the last spot in the array the first spot in the array. I have compared the number read out to my file, and every number is there, but the large number is gone, so I know it works. This is not a suitable fix for me, even if the program does run correctly. I would like to know if anyone knows of a correct solution that would iterate through my file, assign each integer to a spot in the array, but not overflow the array.

Here is the entire program:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::ifstream;

#define MAXSIZE 100

void heapify(int heapList[], int i, int n)  //i shows the index of array and n is the counter
{
     int listSize;
     listSize=n;
     int j, temp;//j is a temporary index for array
     temp = heapList[i];//temporary storage for an element of the array
     j = 2 * i;//end of list
     while (j <= listSize)
     {
          if (j < listSize && heapList[j + 1] > heapList[j])//if the value in the next spot is greater than the value in the current spot
              j = j + 1;//moves value if greater than value beneath it
          if (temp > heapList[j])//if the value in i in greater than the value in j
              break;
          else if (temp <= heapList[j])//if the value in i is less than the value in j
          {
              heapList[j / 2] = heapList[j];//assigns the value in j/2 to the current value in j--creates parent node
              j = 2 * j;//recreates end of list
          }
      }
       heapList[j / 2] = temp;//assigns to value in j/2 to i
       return;
  }

  //This method is simply to iterate through the list of elements to heapify each one

  void buildHeap(int heapList[], int n) {//n is the counter--total list size
       int listSize;
       listSize = n;
       for (int i = listSize / 2; i >= 1; i--)//for loop to create heap
       {
           heapify(heapList, i, n);
       }
   }

   //This sort function will take the values that have been made into a heap and arrange them in order so that they are least to greatest

   void sort(int heapList[], int n)//heapsort
   {
       buildHeap(heapList, n);

       for (int i = n; i >= 2; i--)//for loop to sort heap--i is >= 2 because the last two nodes will not have anything less than them
      {
           int temp = heapList[i];
           heapList[i] = heapList[1];
           heapList[1] = temp;
           heapify(heapList, 1, i - 1);
      }
  }
   //Binary search

   void binarySearch(int heapList[], int first, int last) {//first=the beginning of the list, last=end of the list
       int mid = first + last / 2;//to find middle for search
       int searchKey;//number to search
       cout << "Enter a number to search for: ";
       cin >> searchKey;
       while ((heapList[mid] != searchKey) && (first <= last)) {//while we still have a list to search through
           if (searchKey < heapList[mid]) {
                last = mid - 1;//shorten list by half
            }
           else {
                first = mid + 1;//shorten list by half
           }
           mid = (first + last) / 2;//find new middle
       }
        if (first <= last) {//found number
           cout << "Your number is " << mid << "th in line."<< endl;
       }
        else {//no number in list
           cout << "Could not find the number.";
        }
   }

   int main()
   {
        int j = 0;
        int n = 0;//counter
        int first = 0;

        int key;//to prevent the program from closing
        int heapList[MAXSIZE];//initialized heapList to the maximum size, currently 100
        ifstream fin;
        fin.open("Heapsort.txt");//in the same directory as the program
           while (fin >> heapList[n]) {//read in
                n++;
        }

            heapList[n] = heapList[0];

        int last = n;
        sort(heapList, n);
        cout << "Sorted heapList" << endl;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)//for loop for printing sorted heap
        {
             cout << heapList[i] << endl;
        }
         binarySearch(heapList, first, last);

        cout << "Press Ctrl-N to exit." << endl;
        cin >> key;
   }
```

Comment: You should add unit-tests to verify your program.

Comment: You should access `heaplist[0]` to `heaplist[n-1]` only

Comment: Where would you suggest I put that access in? As soon as we step into my sort function, it's too late, because the large number is moved around to another location.

Answer (score 1):

```
int heapList[MAXSIZE];//initialized heapList to the maximum size, currently 100
```

This comment is wrong - `heapList` array is *declared* not *initialized*, so when you had read all data from the file, index variable `n` will point to the uninitialized cell. Any attempt to use it will invoke an undefined behavior. You could either: initialize an array before using it, decrement `n` value, since it greater than read values number by one, or better use `std::vector` instead of array.

Comment: Although technically correct, this misses the point of the situation - ok, `heapList` starts uninitialized, but is filled with the relevant values in the loop right after. The point is that he's accessing one extra element at the end compared to what he actually read. If the array was initialized - say - to zero, he would still have one spurious value, just zero instead of random junk.

Comment: Exactly. I've tried that, and I still get the large number, because the error is happening in the input, no matter what the array starts out as.

Answer (score 1):

You populate values for `heapsort` for indices `0` to `n-1` only.

Then you access `heaplist` from `1` to `n` which is out of bounds since no value was put in `heapsort[n]`.

Use

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) //instead of i=1 to n
```

Comment: Also, I suggest OP to familiarize with the half-open ranges that are used all the time in programming, this kind d of errors become way easier to avoid.

Comment: I tried inserting a for loop with that format for the sort function in the main, and that did not solve my problem. The other for loop that is printing out the results is not what is resulting in my error.